# Django: Exclude field if select_related() gets used

Tags: django, django-select-related

I  have a Job and Blob model like this:

```
class Job(models.Model):
    id = models.UUIDField(default=uuid.uuid4, primary_key=True)
    start_time = models.DateTimeField()
    input = models.ForeignKey('Blob')


class DeferContentManager(models.Manager):
    use_for_related_fields = True

    def get_queryset(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return super(DeferContentManager, self).get_queryset(*args, **kwargs).defer('content')

class Blob(models.Model):
    content = models.BinaryField()
    name = models.CharField(max_length=10000, default='')


    objects = DeferContentManager()
```

Unfortunately there is an Django ORM query which does this:

```
Job.objects.filter(....).select_related()
```

This loads the BinaryFields of the jobs and we get a MemoryError.

Is there a way to exclude the BinaryField `content` if I do a select_related() query like above?

PS: I know that I could alter the query and use `select_related('non_binary_field')` but a general solution is needed here. I do not have access to the code which does call this line: `Job.objects.filter(....).select_related()`

Comment: could you overwrite select_related method in the DeferContentManager? so the part of the code you cannot access remains unchanged but select_related acts differently

Comment: or override the `Job`'s default Queryset so that you can override it's `select_related` method.

Answer (score 1):

You should define `base_manager_name` in `Meta`.

`use_for_related_fields = True` was [deprecated with 1.10](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/1.10/#manager-use-for-related-fields-and-inheritance-changes) and [removed in 2.0](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/releases/2.0/#features-removed-in-2-0)

See: https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/options/#base-manager-name